# Build a MySQL insert ignore statement with ActiveRecord or AREL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Is there any way to build a MySQL statement like `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` or `UPDATE IGNORE...` using ActiveRecord or AREL?

Comment: I don't think it is out of the box functionality of rails. You can take a look at https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert gem. It may work for you.

Comment: yeah, I saw that gem but it is not what I want, they build the sql query without arel or activerecord
https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert/blob/master/lib/bulk_insert/worker.rb#L128